# Add new parameters to exec procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a custom SQL `exec` to execute stored procedure and send DataTable and execute TableType in sql like:

```
 //Execute 
 db.ExeSQLParam("usp_TaskStatus_Time_Calculation_Final", parameters, "@GuidIdTableType");
```

ExeSQLParam method:

```
public bool ExeSQLParam(string SprocName, DataTable paramArray, string tableTypeName)
        {

            var testc = new SqlParameter();
            bool bFlag = false;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SprocName, this.dbconn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(tableTypeName, SqlDbType.Structured));
            cmd.Parameters[tableTypeName].Value = paramArray;

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                bFlag = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                this.HandleSQLError(e, SprocName, paramArray.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            return bFlag;
        }
```

My question is how can I add to this method another normal parameters , so I can execute as:

```
db.ExeSQLParam("usp_TaskStatus_Time_Calculation_Final", parameters, "@GuidIdTableType", 
@anoteherParameter = 'valueanotherparameter', @other = 'valueoter');
```

How can I achieve that?

I try to change it to received output data as DataTable like:

```
 public DataTable ExeSQLParamAndType(string SprocName, DataTable paramArray, string tableTypeName)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SprocName, this.dbconn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(tableTypeName, SqlDbType.Structured));
            cmd.Parameters[tableTypeName].Value = paramArray;

            DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Table1")
            {
                Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            };
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            try
            {
                da.Fill(tbl);
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetTableBySQL", SprocName);
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            return tbl;
        }
```

but where I can add new parameters? with another `parameters.Add`? I'm a litte confused there

Comment: Yes, you add parameters with cmd.Parameters.Add

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can provide optional parameters using the 'params' keyword, so you simply rewrite your method and supply the params parametres.

Comment: That no help me, I add more information to my question, if you can provide an example it will be very helpfull